# variable regex python

Tags: python, regex, variables

```
MyDir = os.getcwd().split(os.sep)[-1]

command = re.search(r"(MyDir)", body).group(1)

etc
```

hi guys,

am trying to have a python script (on windows)
search my outlook email body for certain words using regex

that works fine, coupled with the rest of the script (not shown)

but the minute i want it to search for a variable, ie **MyDir** it does nothing when i fire off an email to 
myself with the word: **documents** in the body of the email (*documents, being the directory the script is located on this occasion; though should populate the variable with whatever top level directory the script is being run from*)

now i have read and seen that **re.escape** is a method to consider, and have copied lots of different variations, and examples
and adapted it to my scenario, but none have worked, i have built the regex as a string also, still no joy

is there anything in my MyDir "variable" that is throwing the regex search off?

am stumped, its my first python script, so am sure am doing something wrong - or maybe i cant use **os.getcwd().split(os.sep)[-1]** inside regex and have it not look at the variable but the literal string!

thanks for any help, as i have read through similar regex+variable posts on here but havent worked for me

:)

Comment: Andrea, brilliant, i used something like that, but didnt use the double quotes and an inner parenthesis! - thanks, worked perfectly!

Chaker, yours works superbly too, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
command = re.search("(" + re.escape(MyDir) + ")", body).group(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You searching for the string `MyDir` not the variable **MyDir**. You could use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
command = re.search(r"({})".format(MyDir), body).group(1)
```